# Computer Monitor will not display content

Tags: hard-drive, display, vga

I fixed a Dell Dimension E520 computer today. I cleared off the old hard drive and reseated the memory. when I did this, all the diagnostic lights disappeared. The only problem I am having now is with the computer monitor. It acts like the return button was automatically pressed or being held down. This causes the text to run together to form white or multicolored vertical streaks on the screen. You cannot read the text. When the computer is turned on, the Dell Logo appears. The image looks like it's kind of fuzzy. However, I cannot view anything after pressing F2 or from disks in the disk drive.  Here's a picture of it:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I am going to go out on a limb here and say that if you have the wherewithal to repair a computer you have the presence of mind to disconnect the keyboard and mouse before turning the computer on one time to see if that makes any difference.  Assuming it doesn't, from my experience, that looks like a video card problem.  I would suggest you run the aptly named Video Memory Stress Test, there is a way to make a bootable ISO ala Memtest.  Good luck.

http://www.majorgeeks.com/files/details/video_memory_stress_test.html